# Display settings show too many monitors detected

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have a Windows 10 Dell laptop with three monitors plugged in to a Dell Display Link box (two HDMI and one DisplayPort). Everything worked well for several months, but now my Windows display settings show me eight monitors available (there should only be four including the laptop screen).

I had this problem before but rebooting used to be a quick fix.  Now, even a reboot doesn't fix the problem.  I updated my Display Link drivers from version 7.9 to 8.0, but the problem remains.

Any ideas of what to look for?

Comment: Try solution discussed here [http://superuser.com/questions/1142074/windows-10-external-monitor-shows-16-and-my-laptop-display-is-5-what-is-thi](http://superuser.com/questions/1142074/windows-10-external-monitor-shows-16-and-my-laptop-display-is-5-what-is-thi)

Comment: I tried to rollback the Intel Graphics Driver, which fixed the number of monitors issue.  However, every now and then, I get a message saying that the driver crashed (on one of the monitors).  I tried to update the drivers again, but I am not sure if its gonna do it yet.

Comment: Then try reinstalling to specific driver version -> 15.40.4.64.4256 (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25150/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Production-Driver-for-Windows-10-64-bit)

Comment: I have Intel HD Graphics 4600, so your link will not install on my system, I will try 15.40.28.4501...   I still get a message "the driver being installed is not validated for this computer..."

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell XPS 15 with HD Graphics 4600. 
Install the latest driver of the Dell site (this is older than the version of Intel) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HD 4600 in my Dell laptop and I've been having the same issue. After many different Intel drivers I've found that any version after 4463 causes the issue so I've stuck with 4463.

This other question has some more detail on possible fixes: [Windows 10 - External Monitor shows 1|6 and my laptop display is 5 - what is this?](https://superuser.com/questions/1142074/windows-10-external-monitor-shows-16-and-my-laptop-display-is-5-what-is-thi)